# How to accept form input based on model data, but also retain original model object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, primary-key

I simply have a project that uses Linq to SQL to present model data to a View form for editing. My problem is the primary key for that database table is the date + title of post, so if someone edits the title, the post-back of the Model object no longer represents a discover-able object in my database. I feel like there is a really easy solution to this, but I've come to a standstill.

Essentially what I feel like I need to do is have two objects, one for preserving the original data, and one to populate the form for user editing. I'm not sure if that's frowned upon, or what the right way to do that is.

Originally I tinkered with sending the original data to the View as a serialized JSON object, and posting it back with the form. However, that doesn't feel very clean to me, and I imagine there's a way to do it within the framework itself.

**View**

```
@model appname.Models.HomeModel

<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<fieldset>
    <legend>HomeModel</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.News)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.News, new{cols=25, @rows=5})
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Office)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Office)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsDate)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(DateTime date, String title)
    {
        HomeModel model = context.NewsData.Where(x => x.NewsDate == date && x.Title == title).Select(x =>
            new HomeModel(){
                News = x.News,
                Office = x.Office,
                NewsDate = x.NewsDate,
                Title = x.Title
            }).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(model);            
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(HomeModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //This is where it breaks if someone changes the title or date
            //as there's no object in the database matching this query.
            NewsData news = context.NewsData.Where(x => x.NewsDate == model.NewsDate && x.Title == model.Title).Single<NewsData>();
            news.Title = model.Title;
            news.Office = model.Office;
            news.News = model.News;
            news.NewsDate = model.NewsDate;
            context.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Using a free-text field as a key or as part of a composite key is a hugely bad idea. 2) Using composite keys in general is not that great of an idea, either. Rarely are they actually needed, and usually just add complexity to your queries for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Assuming there's a legitimate need for the date + title to always be a unique value, is it still a terrible idea to use a free-text field as part of a composite key? I can see how typically it'd be very unlikely for a text-field to be unique, but what makes it so bad besides complexity?

Comment: Yes, because you can simply set a unique constraint on those columns *without* making them the primary key for the table. And, as for what makes it so bad besides complexity, what more do you need? The worst code out there comes from developers disregarding complexity. Complexity builds on itself, and the more complex your solution becomes, the more bugs you have, the harder it is to maintain, and the more developer suicides you induce. Simplicity should be your focus 100% of the time. Continually and always ask yourself "How can I make this simpler?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why it's always a good idea to have an `identity` field in your database and use that as your primary key. However, I'll just work with the assumption that you have a very good reason for doing it your way.

What you can do is add an `OriginalPost` and `OriginalTitle` properties to your Model that you're passing to the View. Pass those properties the same values as you currently are with your `Title` and whatever the Date field is.

In your Razor, you'll just need to add the following:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OriginalPost)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OriginalTitle)
```

Then when you get back to your Action method, just use those two properties in your model to query the database.

Comment: Thanks krillgar, that's exactly what I was looking for. It's an inherited system so the reasons for not using an identity are unbeknownst to me.

Comment: If you could mark it as an answer so that others will know what worked for you down the line, that'd help the community.

Comment: Would if I could man, too new to mark questions as answers. SE has a threshold before you can accept questions or answers. Let me get some rep and I'll be back :)

Comment: Not a problem. I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 0):

Put `NewsDate`  and `Title` in hidden field in your view

```
@Html.Hidden("OriginalNewsDate",Model.NewsDate)
@Html.Hidden("OriginalTitle",Model.Title)
```

and In your post add two more parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(HomeModel model, string OriginalNewsDate,string OriginalTitle)
{
   // 1. Convert string to date
   // use your LINQ Query
}
```